# How to append select-options from multi-dimension array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4j9sqyeo/)
HTML:

```
<select class="s1"></select>
<select class="s2"></select>
```

JS:

```
var test = [
    ["a","bsafd","cfsaf"],
    ["b","cvxb","cfsf"],
    ["c","hjymb","cfsaf"],
    ["d","vhthb","fsfc","fasfsa"],
    ["e","fsdb","fsfac"],
    ["f","zxczb","vcxc","fsafsd"],
    ["g","yjhdb","bvcbc"],
    ["h","vbnvb","yutkfc"],
    ["i","nbcvnb","ndnfgnmc"],
    ["j","ikgnb","ncnc"],
    ["k","fgncb","kjuc"]
];

$(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++){
        $(".s1").append("<option>"+test[i][0]+"</option>");
    }

    $(".s1").on("change", function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++){ 
            if(test[i].indexOf(value)){
                for(var j=0;j<test[i].length;i++){
                    $(".s2").append("<option>"+test[i][j]+"</option>");
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

I can get the first value from array test and append to the first select area. But I stacked on  the second step. I want to append values to the second select area according to the user selection.

Fon instance, user select "a". The next two values should be append to the second area from the sub array which lead with "a".

Could someone tell me what am I done wrong and how to finish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code [check the inline comments where you did mistake],

```
$(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++){
        $(".s1").append("<option value='"+test[i][0]+"'>"+test[i][0]+"</option>");
        //      -----------------^ add value to all options
    }    
    $(".s1").on("change", function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(".s2").html('');// first make the second drop down blank
        for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++){ 
            if(test[i][0]==value){
                for(var j=0,l=test[i].length;j<l;j++){
                               //----------------^ j++ not i++
                    $(".s2").append("<option>"+test[i][j]+"</option>");
                }
            }
        }
    });        
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/4j9sqyeo/2/)

**Alternatively,** if you make your json as `key-value` pair to differentiate the data for different drop down then it would more simpler to use it like,

```
// json where keys are used fro first drop down and its values are used for second one
var test = {
    "a":["bsafd","cfsaf"],
    "b":["cvxb","cfsf"],
    "c":["hjymb","cfsaf"],
    "d":["vhthb","fsfc","fasfsa"],
    "e":["fsdb","fsfac"],
    "f":["zxczb","vcxc","fsafsd"],
    "g":["yjhdb","bvcbc"],
    "h":["vbnvb","yutkfc"],
    "i":["nbcvnb","ndnfgnmc"],
    "j":["ikgnb","ncnc"],
    "k":["fgncb","kjuc"]
};
$(function(){
    $.each(test,function(i,v){
        // store all keys to first drop down
        $(".s1").append("<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>");
    });

    $(".s1").on("change", function(){
        var value = this.value;
        $('.s2').html('');
        if(value){
            // get the value for the key which is selected
            $(test[value]).each(function(key,data){
                $(".s2").append("<option value='"+data+"'>"+data+"</option>");
            });
        }
    });        
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/4j9sqyeo/7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".s1").on("change", function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var option = '';
    for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++){ 
       /* Checking for first index  */
        if(test[i][0] == value){
            for(var j = 1;j<test[i].length;j++){
                /* creating options  */
                option += '<option>'+test[i][j]+'</option>';

            }

        }
    }
    /* remove previous options and prepend new option by selection  */
   $(".s2").empty().prepend(option);
});
```

Please try this..

[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rut2/4j9sqyeo/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++){           
            if(test[i][0]==value){
                (var j=1;j<test[i].length;j++){                     
                    $(".s2").append("<option>"+test[i][j]+"</option>");
                }
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a multi-dimension array, so you need to loop through or [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the original array to find the matching row and then add the elements of that array starting from `1` instead of `0` to ignore the "key" value:

```
$(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++){
        $(".s1").append("<option>"+test[i][0]+"</option>");
    }

    $(".s1").on("change", function(){
        var value = $(this).val();

        // find the first array which starts with value
        var arr = test.filter(function(v){
            return v[0] == value;
        })[0];

        // store a reference to .s2 so you don;t need to find it every time
        var s2 = $(".s2");
        // remove previous options
        s2.empty();
        for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
            s2.append("<option>"+arr[i]+"</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4j9sqyeo/6/)